# How do I convert a ceiling fan with 2 separate wall switches to a separate fan & light switch?

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

How do I convert a ceiling fan with 2 separate wall switches, 1 for the light and 1 for the fan, to a separate fan & light switch? My next question is it possible to convert the second switch from the ceiling fan to a wall outlet? The ceiling fan has 1 white wire 1 black wire and 1 red wire. I'd appreciate if you could show me wiring diagram if it is possible to convert the second ceiling fan switch to wall outlet.

Answer (score 2):

First off, what room is this in? If this is a bathroom what I am saying DOES NOT apply.

OK, so you have a fan with two separate switches, and you want to convert this into a "dual" fan control? This is easy, just remove the two switches and wire the fan control according to the instructions. 
Then you can take the feed wire from the left over switch, and a pigtailed neutral, and a ground of course, and install a receptacle there.

Sorry, I don't draw diagrams for people, but this is not a difficult install, and besides, to draw a diagram we would need to know exactly what wires are in the switch box.

Here is an example of the control I mean: http://www.homedepot.com/p/Lutron-Skylark-300-Watt-Single-Pole-Dual-Fan-Control-and-Dimmer-Light-Almond-S2-LFSQH-LA/202247983

[image]

Comment: In older homes it is very likely that there will be no neutral conductor in the switch box.

Comment: In a situation like this I would not say it is very likely. Single switch/single light, maybe. Besides, we have no clue how old the home is.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it In many circuits, the fixture is at the end of the line, and the switch is in the middle of the circuit. In those cases both hot and neutral are being fed through the box containing the switch.